# What are the recommended ways to run typescript monorepos in dev environment?

Tags: typescript, monorepo, lerna, ts-node

For the last week, I have been refactoring a really big monolithic repository (npm/typescript) to a monorepo (yarn/lerna/typescript). The transition was quite easy in the beginning, I just refactored files to their respective folders and updated the imports.

The real pain began when I started to experiment with different ways of running the monorepo in "development" (hot reload/watch) mode. I would REALLY like to avoid transpiling every single package on each change (sadly, for now, all of them depend on each other). I used lerna to bootstrap the project and install the modules, and as I can see, lerna links the folders to node_modules, which means every change will be automatically updated in all repos. I have tried a few approaches, and I really need guidance on how to continue or what the standards are.

Problem:

I have a monorepo that contains 3 packages/projects with service classes, and 1 package that is a CLI that uses those packages. When I ran the CLI command with the old monolithic repo using the command:

```
ts-node --transpiler sucrase/ts-node-plugin --project tsconfig.json --require tsconfig-paths/register bin/cli.ts
```

It internally transpiles all the necessary (referenced) ts files and executes in 500ms-1s. That was an acceptable transpile time, which I would like to keep. The second problem that I have is the fact that I use tsconfig paths, which means I have a tsconfig file per package. I would like to keep them, but in the worst case, I will have to replace them with relative paths.

Here are my solutions:

1. Run every directory with tsc-watch, point package.json main entry to dist/index.js, and be done with it. The problem with this is the compilation/transpile time for tsc. It takes around 500ms-1s to compile source files, the .d.ts file generation takes at least 1.5-2s per package and on top of that tspaths take another 500ms to replace (per project). I tried to replace tsc-watch with babel-watch, which was even faster for JS compilation but did not generate the types.
2. Run the same command that was mentioned above with the same file. I tried this, and it seems to be working, but I don't know how to resolve tsconfig paths of the nested packages. For example, the package CLI would resolve its paths with a relative tsconfig, then CLI would find a local package Transpiler (local folder linked to node_modules), which has its own set of paths, which I don't know how to specify. In this case, I would sacrifice ts-paths for really fast dev transpile time. In this case, I would point package.json main to src/index.ts, which would make building hard because I would need to replace it every time I build the project for production. (But that would be the same for step 1)

I was using the [AWS JS SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3) monorepo for guidance and reference.

Project structure:

```
packages
    - cli *(depends on transpiler)*
    - transpiler *(depends on common and statements)*
    - statements *(depends on common)*
    - common *(depends on nothing)*
package.json
tsconfig.json
```

Comment: I'm also looking for a faster dev and was also using tsc in watch mode not long ago. Recently I started using [`lerna watch`](https://github.com/lerna-lite/lerna-lite/tree/main/packages/watch#readme) from Lerna-Lite that I maintained (Lerna also has a watch now). I also added the `tsc --incremental` to make it a bit quicker. It's not as fast as I would like either, but now with lerna watch I only have 1 watch configured in the project root and it now consumes a lot less memory compare to a lot of tsc watch opened for each package. As far as I know, the Types are necessary to code in monorepo

Comment: I have voted to close this question as opinion-based as you are specifically asking *What are the recommended ways to ___*. For more information, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask.

Answer (score 3):

After I wrote a comment earlier to your question. I actually did some more digging and found this great article [Boost your productivity with TypeScript project references](https://blog.logrocket.com/boost-your-productivity-with-typescript-project-references/) and decided to give it a try.

To provide a bit more info about my monorepo project, my project is [Slickgrid-Universal](https://github.com/ghiscoding/slickgrid-universal), it has 17 packages in the monorepo and I use [Lerna-Lite](https://github.com/lerna-lite/lerna-lite) (which is a ligher version of Lerna that I also maintain), prior to each test run, I delete all `dist/` folders and then compared both approaches time execution

1. executing `lerna run` command took about **1m30sec**
2. executing `tsc -b` with TypeScript References took **18sec**

Wow I can't believe that I have been missing out on this `tsc -b` (or `--build`) with [TypeScript References](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html) it is **5x faster**, just Wow, **and** that is also including declaration files creation (d.ts). We can also add the watch mode (also note that it's incremental by nature, so no need to add `--incremental`)

```bash
tsc --build ./tsconfig.packages.json --watch
```

I also tried to test another thing, I wanted to see how long it takes in watch mode to propagate the Types from one package to another when I add a new property into an existing interface, in my project I have a `common` package (which is my biggest package and has hundreds of interfaces) and then I waited to see how long it takes for the interface to be reflected in my frontend package and it took about **10sec** in my editor to show up, it's not bad but I was actually expecting (hoping) for a lower value. In fact, the 10sec is very similar to my previous implementation of using `lerna watch` with `tsc --incremental` in each package, so I don't see that much gain on that side. The real gain is really on the first clean build, 18sec vs 1m30sec on my entire monorepo including Type declarations is just amazingly fast compare to before the change.

Can we go faster?

There might be another approach which I read about, but never really tried it, which is to simply do type checking (which is what ViteJS and ESBuild are doing) without producing the declaration files via the command `tsc --noEmit`. However, I'm not entirely sure, but I think with this approach, it's probably better to build the Types at least once and then after use `--noEmit` in watch mode. However, I'm not really sure that would work well in a monorepo structure (most probably not) since importing from another package of the mono has to go through `package.json` of that imported package to find its location and I assume that this will require the Types to exist in order to be able to use TypeScript in the editor. So in summary, I think this new option 2. is what I will use from now on (I also applied this change to [Lerna-Lite](https://github.com/lerna-lite/lerna-lite) after writing this answer).

Note, I also wonder if this `tsc -b` would work with other tools like TurboRepo or Nx. I'm not using any of these tools but I'm guessing that it might not work or there's some quirks around that. So I'm guessing that with these tools, you would still require a separate `tsc` command in each package. It might still be faster with these tools when using caching because you would only build the package that you changed, but still `tsc -b` is also quite fast.

EDIT

After refactoring my code and create a [PR](https://github.com/ghiscoding/slickgrid-universal/pull/912), I found some a few things to keep in mind

- a caveat with using TypeScript References and Composite is, because of its structure, that we can only do this with **only 1 configuration** which mean that, sadly, we can't really run multiple different builds with different settings (ie: CJS, ESM), at least not that I'm aware of.
- In the end I decided to still keep my original `lerna watch` which uses `tsc --incremental` (not composite) in each package for couple of reasons

  1. I also watch SASS files and want to keep a single lerna watch for all file extensions (`.ts`, `.scss`).
  2. using `lerna watch` with `tsc --incremental` in the package that changed, is about the same time as if I would have run `tsc -b --watch` from the root, so if I'm not gaining any speed in development, so for that reason, I prefer to keep the single lerna watch that I already have setup instead of having multiple watches (1x tsc watch, multiple SASS watches since I have a few SASS themes which would open a lot more threads)
  3. `lerna watch` seems to take less resources (mem/cpu usage) than `tsc --watch` does, at least on Windows. Note that a single tsc watch is still a magnitude better than having multiple tsc watch for each package but since I also watch SASS files the single lerna watch is more efficient compare to having multiple SASS watches.
- these last 3 points might be irrelevant to your project, `tsc -b` is still the way to go forward whenever possible.

Regardless of these last 3 points, I'm still running `tsc -b` in the root prior to starting the `lerna watch` because it's quite fast and I need the Types to exist when starting development, however when that step is done, I simply rely on `lerna watch` to run `tsc --incremental` on the package that changed. It's not the fastest but it's still a lot better than what I had before. Perhaps with this approach, I might be able to use `lerna watch` and `tsc --noEmit` for type checking only (I might give that a try in the future when I get more time). I also run `tsb -b` from the root when running my Cypress E2E tests since I don't need the watch while testing and `tsc -b` is extremely fast, so I saved nearly 1.5min from that CI job alone.

I also found this other article [Using TypeScript Project References with ts-loader and Webpack](https://medium.com/@nickexcell/using-typescript-project-references-with-ts-loader-and-webpack-part-1-5d0c3cd7c603) to be quite helpful and informative as well

Comment: Very informative! Curious if you’ve had to deal with a situation where you want to separate a package for reuse & testability, but don’t want to publish it and instead you’d rather bundle it with some other package’s distribution. I see you have `common`, but you seem to be publishing it so I guess you haven’t tried to go that way?

Comment: all my packages are published and the `common` has to be published since that is the core of my entire library, without it, it would simply not work so yes it has to be published. I do not bundle anything, it's published as regular TypeScript package, the only time that it's being bundled is by the end user of my lib when they create a SPA (single page app). The only package that is not to be published is the demo and I simply have it set to `private: true` and that makes it not publishable since Lerna/Lerna-Lite will not publish private package.

Comment: “ entire library, without it, it would simply not work so yes it has to be published ” You can use `common` from other libraries in the same monorepo, but not publish it. But you would need to configure bundler to include `common` with end-user libraries directly when they’re built (instead of referencing as a normal dependency). That’s what I’m trying to do with esbuild…